# What is the associated ideal of this closed subset in $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $f$ be an irreducible homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ in $n + 1$ variables with $n \geq 3$. Then $f$ defines a hypersurface $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. We will associate to each point $P = (a_0: \ldots : a_n) \in \mathbb{P}^n$ a hyperplane $H_P \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ described by the equation $a_0 x_0 + \cdots + a_n x_n = 0$.

(i) Show that the set of points $P \in \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $H \cap H_p$ is a variety, is a non-empty open subset $U_f$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

(ii) Take $n=3$. Describe the associated ideal $V_f : = \mathbb{P}^n \setminus U_f$.

**Attempt:** For (i), I tried to prove that $U_f$ is non-empty by using a Veronese embedding, but I think my proof is incorrect. Also, I have no idea on how to show that $U_f$ is an open subset.

(ii) Is it possible to give an explicit ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ so that $V_f=Z(\mathfrak{a})$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but shouldn't $U_f := \{p \in \mathbb{P}^n | H \cap H_p \text{ is a variety} \}$ and not $U_f = H \cap H_p$ as you've written? The latter is definitely not open.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I messed up. I edited it

Comment: Consider the case where $f(X)=X^3-Y^2(Y+Z+T)$. On the point $p$ corresponding to the hyperplane $Y=0$, $H \cap H_p$ is a variety (it is $\{X=Y=0\}$). However, on the point $p_t$ corresponding to $Y=t(T+Z)$ $t \neq -1$, $H \cap H_{p_t}=\{X^3-(1+t)Y^3\}$ is not a variety. So the set of such $p$ is not closed. I suggest adding some sort of nondegeneracy assumption, so that $f \neq L_1^3+L_2C_1$, where $L_1,L_2$ are linear factors and $C_1$ is quadratic.

Comment: @Kamil Are you working over a field? Do you assume it to be algebraically closed or of a certain characteristic? What does variety mean for you (reduced, irreducible, etc)? Further, do you or do you not assume that $V(f)$ is smooth?

Comment: We work over algebraically closed field $K$. Variety means: closed irreducible subset of the ambient space. I think we may assume $V(f)$ to be smooth.

Comment: Hi ! Are you aware of Bertini's theorem ? (Hartshorne II.8.18 and III.7.9.1 ? Reading the proof carefully should give you the answer (or at least some ideas).

Comment: I'm not aware of it. We are still at chapter I in Hartshorne. But I will check it.

Comment: The problem is incorrect as stated: it's true that generic hyperplane sections of irreducible projective varieties are again irreducible, see section 3 [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1950-069-00/S0002-9947-1950-0037548-0/S0002-9947-1950-0037548-0.pdf), but this only means that the locus of hyperplanes producing irreducible sections contains a dense open set, not that it _is_ a dense open set, per Mindlack's example. This paper was published before the introduction of schemes, so it could theoretically be accessible given your technology, being somewhere in Hartshorne ch I. (con't)

Comment: (2/2) I'd be surprised if this was truly the intended solution, though. You should go talk with your professor and report back about what they were looking for - I'm sure we'd all be interested to see this! Also, assuming $V(f)$ smooth doesn't fix it without more work, either - the idea here would be that the generic hyperplane section would be smooth and connected (by Hartshorne's Bertini, mentioned above) thus irreducible, but you would need a good description of how irreducible but singular sections sit in this locus, which isn't immediate.